# UISearchBar appearing at *bottom* of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

Hope someone knows what to do, this is driving me nuts !

I've got a very simple UITableViewController, in an existing application, to which I have added a UISearchBar using interface builder (drag n drop)

Note: This problem exists when testing in either iOS 6 or iOS 7

My problem is that when the application is run, the searchbar is displayed at the BOTTOM of the results

[image]

When I click into the search area to perform a search, the searchbar then flicks to the top of the page

[image]

At first I thought "this is me", so I deleted the controller completely, including all code, and rebuilt from scratch the page in order to avoid any mistake I may have made.  Unfortunately with the same result

The structure in IB is :

[image: structure]

The controller code just does bare basic at the minute, just `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: follow this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view

Comment: Thanks, I've just skimmed through that, doesn't help unfortunately as I've setup a simple UITableViewController and dropped the SearchBar and Controller object onto the top of the TableView below the navigation bar.  Good link though, thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just add a prototype cell and put the search bar on top. You don't have to ever use the prototype cell.

Comment: without any prototype cells it's difficult to tell if you have added it as a header or footer.

Comment: Yes that's why I said to add a cell.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean about not knowing if its a header or footer.  Another follow on from that, would this still be applicable if I were using custom cells instead of standard ones ?

Comment: The cell does not matter in this case. You just have to put the search bar in the right place and that is above the cells not below. When you have no cells in storyboard its hard to do that.

Comment: FANTASTIC !! I've got this working in my original application now that uses custom cells and it's solved the issue.  I originally thought I couldnt have a prototype as I was using customcell, seems thats not the issue.  Many, many, thanks !!

Comment: No problem. It was easy.

Comment: In my opinion it's not the right way. A property in searchbar is missing to set header, footer. But it's a nice workaround- btw it still exist in Xcode 8 with xib files